# After macOS update WebStorm, Android Studio doesn't see node and yarn

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, global-variables, webstorm

I recently updated macOS and now every time I open programs such as WebStorm or Android Studio it says that its missing node.js. The problem is that `node` is callable from terminal. Also if I open those programs from terminal with `open`, it seems like it working fine.

My current macOS version is Monterey 12.4 (MacBook Pro 13 M1)
WebStorm 2021.1
Android Studio 2020.3.1 beta 4

Also I'm using nvm.

Here's output of my `PATH` variable and `node` path.

`echo "${PATH//:/\n}"`:

```
/Users/danilaberencev/.nvm/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin
/opt/homebrew/bin
/opt/homebrew/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Library/Apple/usr/bin
/Users/danilaberencev/Library/Android/sdk/emulator
/Users/danilaberencev/Library/Android/sdk/tools
/Users/danilaberencev/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin
/Users/danilaberencev/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```

`which node`:

```
/Users/danilaberencev/.nvm/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node
```

Comment: node is not on your `$PATH` - that's the issue; on MacOSX the environment variables differ between GUI applications and within the terminal. Terminal environment is only available to applications started from terminal. To solve this problem, WebStorm tries to load terminal environment by executing some scripts on startup, but it seems that it can't retrieve all needed stuff in your case

Comment: I edited my original post with $PATH output

Comment: it's on your `$PATH` in terminal but not in IDE - unless you start it from terminal to have it inherit the terminal environment.

Comment: I'm specified node path in IDE, but every new project can't find node again, which was never the case before update. How should I fix this all at once? Also now I wonder how it worked before because I never specified node path in IDEs